# My internet goes out every few minutes and the resolution is opening "select network" in the menu

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless

This is an intermittent issue and I haven't figured out what causes this but every once in a while my internet will go out every 2 minutes or so and if I open up network settings and go to select network the internet comes back. I don't even have to select a network, simply opening the menu makes the internet reconnect. I don't know where to begin troubleshooting a problem like this, here are my system details:

Network Card:

```
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 31
   serial: 00:f4:8d:b2:07:19
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.4.0-146-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=10.0.0.133 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:131 memory:a4000000-a41fffff
```

Ubuntu: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Kernal: 5.4.0-146-generic

EDIT: here is the output of the troubleshooting script: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/nC274QByhd/

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of this troubleshooting script mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/425180). Also, FYI, 18.04 only has a few days left of community support. Don't forget to release upgrade in the coming days.

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was released in 2018-April (thus 18.04 with the *year.month* format used by Ubuntu) with 5 years of *standard* supported life; ie. until 2023-April.. which was extended for 1 month (now 31-May-2023) so your system will soon be EOSS. I'd also check your details; 18.04.2 would imply you're well behind on upgrades & also using the 4.18 kernel - but you show 5.4 which was from 18.04.5??  A fully-upgraded 18.04 system will report itself as 18.04.6.   Are you using Ubuntu?  (*your contradictory facts imply it's a Ubuntu based system & not Ubuntu*)

Comment: I wasn't aware my system was about to lose support, thanks for the heads up! I'll be honest I don't know the difference between an "ubuntu base system" and "ubuntu". I set up my windows machine to dual boot ubuntu about 3 or 4 years ago. Btw, I updated my original post

Comment: You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm the status of your actual install anytime..  (*that command being replaced by `ubuntu-security-status` for modern releases though)

Comment: 99.7% of my packages are unsupported, LOL. I know what I'm doing tonight.